# New McAfee antivirus disables Windows XP access to printers?

Tags: windows-xp, printing, windows-server-2003

On Friday at the end of the day we updated our in-house servers to run the newer McAfee SaaS Endpoint Protection Suite, which involved restarting the servers.  This morning (Monday) our Windows XP machines cannot access printers shared from those servers.  They can still log on (the server with the printer in question is also the Active Directory server) and access file shares.  I haven't been able to find any relevant entries in the Event Viewer on the server.

The server is Windows Server 2003.  The printer is an HP LaserJet M2727nf.  The error text in Windows is

> "Windows cannot connect to the printer.  Either the printer name was typed incorrectly, or the specified printer has lost its connection to the network."

The message comes up when logon scripts run, and when I try to open the printer from the Printers and Faxes area of Control Panel.  Windows 7 computers seem to be fine.  I don't see any errors in the Network Summary page from the printer.

The firewall installed by McAfee is not a factor.  Is there anything else it could have changed to affect printer sharing to Windows XP only?  I'm also not 100% sure it's the McAfee installation that's causing the problem, but it's the most significant change that's happened since the last time printing worked.

UPDATE 2/22/2011: I tried updating the [HP drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=3377075&prodNameId=3377076&swEnvOID=228&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=ma-54987-3) on the XP machines.  The executable "installer" for the new drivers did not actually install anything, it just extracted files to an unspecified location.  As per the instructions I removed the printer and re-added it.  This seemed to solve the problem, but this morning when users logged on, the problem came back.

Comment: @Moab - in this case, that's a bad idea.  You can't install security essentials on Windows Server.

Comment: @ Joel, yup, but I stick with the McAfee comment, junk software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  The server in question had two Ethernet ports, and one was disabled.  Enabling it stopped the errors.  We're not sure how that worked, but it did.